# how to solve "ImportError: libcxcore.so.1" error while installing blobs package

Tags: python, opencv, blobs, cvblobslib

I have an problem while trying to install opencv blobs package on ubuntu12.04.i'm not able to install it. i'm getting the below error which i mentioned.

```
 import _BlobResult
 ImportError: libcxcore.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone tell me to solve this error.

Comment: unfortunately, cvblobslib is from the stone-age, and relies on opencv1.x . if you have a more recent cv2 module around, you probably don't need cvblobslib, almost all the functionality could be done with onboard means, e.g. cv2.findContours()

Comment: @berak is it a version problem??

Comment: yes. cvblobs relies on an outdated opencv version. ( you probably got something more recent installed, libcxcore is gone since 5 or 6 years already )

Comment: @berak oh fine.. will check it and tell u

Comment: just take a 2 minute break, and find out if you really need it at all, or if instead you can use cv2.findContours() or cv2.moments() ( the recommended way). apart from the installation problem, the code used in cvblobslib will be incompatible with today's (e.g numpy)

Comment: yes definitely needed blobs package. i'm getting the above error while installing blobs package.

Comment: i'd just strongly advise you *against* using it. and code that depends on that *will* be horribly outdated, too.

Comment: thanks. but i have to refer that code only.thats why i'm trying to solve this type of error which i mentioned above.